# How do I make different distributions objectively comparable?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, standardization, uncertainty, t-distribution

I have some model, $f(x)$, that takes in some input and produces some output. Now my input are random variables distributed according to some distribution. The output are also random variables with some distribution, however it is different.

### Problem

The input distribution represents prices. Now, I have very few real data available, so I want to quantify the uncertainty of the model. In other words, **I want to try a few realistic input distributions of these prices, and see how these affect the outcome distribution**. In particular, I was thinking of normal distribution, t-distribution, lognormal distribution and triangle distribution.

*For example: how do normally distributed prices affect the variance of the output? How does a students-t distributed prices affect the VaR of the model?*

In any case, I want to try to compare these outcomes as **objectively** as possible, hence I want to make the inputs objectively comparable.

But then the problem arises, how can I make the inputs objectively comparable?

I am starting off with distributions like this. `y1` is a normal distribution and `y2` a t-distribution.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy; from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(size=10_000)
print(y1.var(), y1.mean())

y2 = scipy.stats.t.rvs(df=1, size=10_000)
print(y2.var(), y2.mean())
```

### Idea 1

I standardise all my input distributions to have `mean = 1` and `std = 1`. Now they have same mean and same variance or std, and I can compare them. THe problem I see with this method that especially distributions with long tails, such as students-t, will become very squished.

E.g. in an extreme case, it will look like this. Orange is t-dist, Blue is normal, both are standardised

```py
plt.hist(y1, alpha=0.3, bins=np.linspace(-4,4,100))
plt.hist(((y2 - np.mean(y2)) / np.std(y2)), alpha=0.3, bins=np.linspace(-4,4,100))
plt.show()
```

[image]

However now the student-t dist looks very squished, and it is not what I want. The only advantage are that they are objectively comparable because they have the same mean and std, so if there are changes arising in the output of the model I can attributed them to the shape of the distribution and not the parameters. Or can I??

### Idea 2

I leave them as similar as possible. For example, I could do so by fixing their 10% quantile on either side to some fixed distance from the center / mean. Now, the majority of the 'mass' of the distribution (i.e. 80%) is within the same range for all of them, however the empirical features that I care about, such as e.g. the long tails, are still present.

```py
y3 = y2 * (np.quantile(y1, q=0.1) / np.quantile(y2, q=0.1))
plt.hist(y1, alpha=0.3, bins=np.linspace(-4,4,100))
plt.hist(y3, alpha=0.3, bins=np.linspace(-4,4,100))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Overall this looks much better, but the problem I see is that now e.g. students-t has a much larger std, so If I see more variance in the output of my model, It is somewhat expected as the input also had lots more variance. Is that then a problem that hinders objective comparison?

### Question / Summary

I just presented 2 ideas to solve a problem I have, but I want to know

- which of the 2 solutions is better, if any is?
- Are there other approaches that allow me to compare distributions more objectively, such that I can attribute the output of my model more objectively to the input
- Should I just leave the distribution as is?
- Any papers or research on this? Searching the internet for `objectively comparing distributions`, I could not find much ...

### Edit: Clarification for comment

Ok so I can describe the problem and what I want to achieve more clearly, however I am not sure I exactly understand what details you are looking for.

I am modeling an energy market. There are auctions on this market, and I assume that the prices achievable are random distributed according to some PDF. However I dont know the PDF. I can only guess it, or do some assumptions. For example, I can assume they are normally distributed, or that they are t-distributed, hence there are more outliers.

Now I am pricing an asset on this market using a real options approach. Essentially, I simulate the price of this asset over 1 year participation in this market. To be precise, the price of the asset is computed as a call option on the market price, that is $V = \max(S-K, 0)$, with K the strike price. Now after 1 year, the price of the asset, since it depends on the random prices of the energy in the market, is also random. If I simulate this e.g 1000 times, i get a distribution of random values. I am interested in some statistics, e.g the mean, variance, 95% quantile (for [VaR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk)) etc.

And I do this whole process with the aim of quantifying my uncertainity. E.g. what kind of mean price do we get when prices are distributed according to this particular distribution. This is important, because you may want some info before investing into building the asset that participates in the market.

And now coming to my problem: I compare the outcome of the asset price (i.e. the mean, VaR, variance, .. of the model over e.g. 1000 simulations) for 2 distributions, e.g. normal and t. I find that the output variance is much larger when the price distribution is t-distributed, which may be because the variance of the t-distribution is larger. Now if i make the variance of the input t-distribution the same as the one of the input normal distribution, then the t-distribution will become very squished. Also potentially not ideal.

Comment: Due to the extreme generality in which this situation is described, it looks like most of the information that is usually relevant to a statistical problem (such as a loss function) is absent, making it impossible to offer appropriate or objective answers.  Please consider telling us about the problem you actually face.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I appended a small clarification. Let me know if things are still unclear.